# Retrieve and store certain ID in SQL and to use them in a further query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have in an Oracle database the following situation:

Table T1 with attributes ID and T2_ID.
Table T2 with attributes ID and T3_ID.
Table T3 with attributes ID and T4_ID.
Table T4 with attribute ID.

Each TX_ID is referring to the ID of the related table (example: T3_ID = ID in table T3).

Given an ID in T1, I would like to write a SQL-script to know the related T3_ID and T4_ID, store them in single variables (containing only the retrieved values) and use those values for other operations of DELETE/SELECT in the same script (like DELETE all the rows from another T* table which have T*_ID = T3_ID).

Is there a way to do that in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a PLSQL block, use something like this to fetch data in variables `v_t3_id` and `v_t4_id` and use that in your delte/update statements.

```
select t3.id,t4.id into v_t3_id,v_t4_id 
from t1 
left join t2 on t1.t2_id=t2.id
left join t3 on t2.t3_id=t3.id
left join t4 on t3.t4_id=t4.id
where t1.id=<your value>
```

If data set is huge, then google on how to use `BULK COLLECT` to do the same.

Comment: This may work, but how can I store t3.id and t4.id which you are selecting, to use them in a further operation like `DELETE * from T_NEW where T_NEW.ID = t3.id`?

Comment: That is what getting captured in `v_t3_id` and `v_t4_id` by `INTO` clause. Use these variables.

Comment: So if I say in your select `SELECT t3.id AS pippo, t4.id AS pluto into ...` can I also say later `DELETE * FROM T_NEW where T_NEW.ID = pluto`?

Comment: `Alias` and `Variable` are 2 different things. `pippo` will be an alias. In my example `v_t3_id` is a variable you can save `t3.id` to. You need `into` clause to capture the selected record in a variable. Please go through sample PLSQL programs to understand what INTO is doing to better understand your requirement.

Comment: I got it now. I wasn't familiar with the into condition. Thanks for helping.